# How can I give items to a friend in my party?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know item drops are unique to players, and whatever drops drops for your eyes only.

However, I was able to drop an item from my inventory and a friend saw it and picked it up.
Does this confirm that whatever I drop is no longer for me only? Do I have to be aware that people in my party can "steal" items I drop?

What are other, more secure, ways to give an item to a friend? Can I send it to them without the need for our characters to be standing next to each other?

What about items I place in containers? Are they also visible to my whole party?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monster drops are seen individually,however once you pick up item and drop it again it can be seen by others,also not picking up items or leaving them on the ground will make them available to other players.

To make a proper trade you can **right click on a player portrait** and open up a trade window.

Not sure what you mean by placing item in a container  :/  ...If you mean stash it is visible only by you,if you mean on the drops from crashing the barrels...It is the same as with monster drops.